# is using react context in more places, more costy?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```
<SuperComponent>
  <ChildComponent />
  <ChildComponent />
</SuperComponent>
```

Assuming we have an context controlled by a reducer, and it's an object that contains needed data for all `ChildComponent`s. And let's assume instead of 2 children, we have like 10-15 children.

Is it better to call `useContext` once in `SuperComponent` then pass the needed data to children as props, or call `useContext` in each `ChildComponent` individually?

Comment: it is more of a personal choice. My opinion is passing context from parent to child as props is more clean rather than using `useContext` in each and every child

Answer (score 1):

If each child only needs a small subset of the data, then it can be more performant to have the parent component get the entire object once, and then pass individual props to the children. When the context value changes, the parent component will be forced to rerender, but each child component can potentially skip its render by using react.memo (or shouldComponentUpdate) if the piece it cares about hasn't changed.

If each child needs all the data, then this won't let you skip any renders; they'll all have to render when the context changes. So in that case, it becomes better for the children to consume the context directly, so that the parent component can potentially skip rendering.

Note that in both cases, you only get the performance improvements if you use react.memo. If you don't, then everything rerenders all the time anyway.